# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Database of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Database of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Error shown at Android studio

```
   W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Database of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
    at com.abc.SignUp_Activity$6.onResponse(SignUp_Activity.java:122)
    W/System.err:     at com.abc.SignUp_Activity$6.onResponse(SignUp_Activity.java:118)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
    at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
    E/anyText: Database connected{"success":"0","message":"success"}
```

Android code:

```
private void registerUser() {
    final String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String name = etName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("REGISTERING ACCOUNT......!!");
    progressDialog.show();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "FILL ALL THE FIELD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                URL_REGIST,
                //Getting error here//  new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //Getting error here//   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            //Getting error here//   String success = jsonObject.getString("success");

                            if (success.equals("0")) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(SignUp_Activity.this, "REGISTER SUCCESS......!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUp_Activity.this, "EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS...!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("anyText", response);
                            Toast.makeText(SignUp_Activity.this, "ERROR CREATING ACCOUNT....!!"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp_Activity.this, "REGISTER FAIL..........!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

i am having error on above code and also write the place where having this error

My php code:

**

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST'){

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

require_once 'connect.php';

$sql = "INSERT INTO users_table (name, email, password) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$password')";

if ( mysqli_query($conn,$sql) ) {
    $result["success"] = "0";
    $result["message"] = "success";

    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);

}
else {

    $result["success"] = "1";
    $result["message"] = "error";

    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}}?>
```

i think myphp code is good but at above android code is having a error which i don't understand it.

Comment: At your php header add json header at top of json_encode `header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);` hope this help

Comment: Sory friends for miss understand,  i'm move my comment to answere

Answer (score 0):

Try to change type request to json object

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.POST, URL_REGIST, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
```

And change `requestQueue.add(stringRequest);` to `requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);`
Hope this help

EDIT :
You can Change like This

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.POST, URL_REGIST, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                //Getting error here//  new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("RESPONSE",response.toString())
                        try {
                            //Getting error here//   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = response.getString("success");

                            if (success.equals("0")) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(SignUp_Activity.this, "REGISTER SUCCESS......!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(SignUp_Activity.this, "EMAIL ALREADY EXISTS...!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("anyText", response);
                            Toast.makeText(SignUp_Activity.this, "ERROR CREATING ACCOUNT....!!"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp_Activity.this, "REGISTER FAIL..........!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: when i write your code i have to do lots of changing on coding and when i am doing that its just getting more red line. not one specific...

Comment: my whole code is based on string if you see code above, so if i remove string and its get error also in                                                                                 @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("name", name);
                    params.put("email", email);
                    params.put("password", password);
                    return params;

Comment: At red line you can press alt+enter if show import you can select import

Comment: i did Enter alt+enter, but from your code my string getting remove from inside eventListener

Comment: i do that also, but at down see in Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(); this getting disturb if i remove string and put JsonObject on parameter.

Comment: ok bro,you can roll back your code and at `onResponse(String response) {` you can add log like `onResponse(String response) {Log.d("respose",response.toString());...`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the stacktrace, the exception message and the source code for the Android JSONObject and JSON classes, it is clear that you are calling `new JSONObject` with the string "Database" as its argument.  That is failing ... naturally.

It appears that the `response` string is not what you think it is. You should be able to confirm this by logging the value of `response` before you attempt to decode it.

(Note: the commented out code makes it uncertain what you are *actually* running on the Java side.  I presume that you are calling `new JSONObject(String)` ... but that is commented out.  Your stacktrace and code do not match.  Similarly, I am doubtful of the PHP code ... because I can't see how it could generate "Database" as a response.)

There are probably more elegant ways to handle the response -> JSON conversion (see other answers), but I think that the **real** problem is that the response you are getting is not valid JSON ...

Comment: yes exactly new JSONObject(String) is having problem, but i can't solve it that's why here :(

Comment: @AsmatKhoso - The problem is that you are calling it with bad input.  You need to figure out why.  Also, I would advise you to stop "fiddling" with the code.  You need to understand what is going wrong *first*.  If you keep changing things without understanding the problem you will only succeed in *confusing yourself*.